# Linux bash: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, linux

I have a java program `Read` which reads file from an URL looks like this:
`file://myhost/system.log`

On Windows I use this command:

`java Read "file://myhost/system.log"`

and it works flawlessly.

But on Linux when I try to use the same command it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
        at read.readInput(ReadHTML.java:53)
        at read.readInput.main(ReadHTML.java:76)
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
I think I found the problem:
`myhost` is not mounted on the Linux machine so that it cannot connect to it by using `file://...`

Thanks for all the answers, guys!

Comment: This is probably a networking issue. Any firewalls? Are they all on the same network?

Comment: They are on the same network. It doesn't seems to be any networking issue, but I will double check.

Comment: You say the URL looks like `file:///` but the stack hints at `FTP` protocol. Are you sure this is the right URL ?

Comment: As @Isaac stated below, it seems that it tries to connect through the ftp protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your program (by virtue of using a `file` URL on a Linux OS) is attempting to open an FTP connection to the host specified in the URL. The establishment of the FTP connection fails.

This could be due to a variety of issues. Try connecting with ftp directly:

`ftp myhost`

And I'm guessing it'd fail as well. Do you have an FTP server installed & running?

Comment: Is `FTP` some kind of default protocol when using `file://host/...` URLs ?

Comment: This is mostly likely the case, I don't have an ftp server installed and running. On Windows I can simply access the file by typing `file://myhost/system.log` in the browser

Comment: @jvivenot, it is possible. I haven't checked it myself, though. Having said that, consider this: if a host name is specified in the `file` protocol, then the file - if accessed - must be accessed through some *networking* protocol. It could be FTP, SMB/CIFS, NFS... depending on the JDK's implementation. SMB/CIFS seems to be more fitting under windows; under linux... well, it could be FTP or NFS.

Comment: @Newbie, if you specify a `host` in the `file` URL under Windows, Windows most likely uses its regular SMB/CIFS protocol to access that file. Under linux, behaviour is different. Do you *have* to specify a host? in other words, is there any restriction as to where the file actually resides? Can it only be a local file, or can it be a remote file as well?

Comment: @Unfortunately, yes:( I have to specify a host. It is file stored locally on `myhost`

Comment: Is there a way to implement SMB/CIFS protocol on UNIX without install any extra packages?

Comment: @Newbie, SMB/CIFS may or may not be shipped with your Linux distribution. There are thousands of distributions out there so it's hard to say. You will have to speak with your Linux box owner to see whether SMB/CIFS is already installed. Regardless, however... even if an SMB client is installed, it doesn't mean that the `ftp` URL protocol will end up using it. The JDK will use whatever "URL handler" that it was defined to use, for handling the `file` protocol. Read about URL handlers in the JDK documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason can be that hosts.allow  does not have entry of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just need a third /. The correct syntax for file uris is file://[path] but [path] should begin with a /.